# Custom Form Events on Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have created custom event for "New Registrations". Added Datalayer:

window.dataLayer.push({
    'event' : 'RegistrationSuccessful',
    'formName' : 'Register Form'
  });

Now, When I am debugging a page, getting message **"Tags Not Fired On This Page"** but on the left side it shows Registration Successful. (Please see the screenshot)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKgAu.png)

Can Anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Could you post some more screenshots?
your register form tag setup
your register form trigger setup

Comment: Yes, You can see here: oi65.tinypic.com/b4jcz8.jpg.  oi66.tinypic.com/2nscgnk.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing Tags and Events. If you wish to fire your 'Register Form' tag on 'RegistrationSuccessful' event you first have to setup new trigger in your GTM e.g. go to Triggers -> NEW
[image]

Once you save this trigger you can assing it to your 'Register Form' Tag like this: go to Tags -> Register Form Tag
[image]

You should be all set but I would recomend looking up help pages: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103657?hl=en

Good luck.

Comment: Trigger is already setup for "Register Form" tag. You can see here: http://oi65.tinypic.com/b4jcz8.jpg.  

http://oi66.tinypic.com/2nscgnk.jpg

FYI. I am tracking Event not Page views. Please help me!!

Comment: Unless you have multiple form submits which can trigger the same `RegistrationSuccessful` event, you should remove the `Form ID` rule. By the way, loved you in Transformers.

Comment: I have a Login form on a same page but using different trigger for login successful tag. Do you think I am going to get correct results?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try removing the form id condition from your trigger. From your screenshots that's the only possible problem I can see. It should also be unnecessary if you've set your dataLayer event push up properly.

Comment: You are right, But I have two forms on a single page i.e. Login and Register. I don't think, without the formID I am able to track both tags separately. What are your suggestions?

Comment: Could you push two separate events? So for example

window.dataLayer.push({ 'event' : 'RegistrationSuccessful' });

window.dataLayer.push({ 'event' : 'LoginSuccessful' });

If not you'll need tolook at the form id variable to see what is going wrong there.

Comment: Already pushed two different events for both Login and Register. I just want to ensure that I the results(count) don't get merged. 

Let's suppose if user login into a website and it will also counted in the registration event. Is that possible without the Form ID?